# MTDB movie database plugin install without going through index.php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, url-rewriting

I want to install MTDB movie database plugin without going through index.php file
such as www.mysite/install rather than www.mysite/index.php/install
my .htacess file goes here

    
        Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```